# The Hot Dog Vendor: Daily or Weekly Probability When Forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

As a production planner, a variant of the following example has been bothering me for a long time; hopefully someone here can help me to view the problem in the right manner.  Let's consider a hypothetical vendor that has been selling hot dogs at the same location from Monday thru Friday each week for many years.  Over this period, daily sales have been normally distributed with a mean of 150 and a standard deviation of 50.  Accordingly, weekly sales have exhibited a mean of 750 and standard deviation of 112. On Thursday night of the current week, he notices that total sales for the week are already at 750 hot dogs.  What is the probability that he will sell 150 hot dogs on Friday?  From the standpoint of daily sales, it would be 50%.  From the standpoint of weekly sales, it would be about 9%. Which is correct? The practical issue is this: If the number of hot dogs he needs to sell in order to breakeven for the day is 100, should he open his stand or take the day off on Friday?

Comment: It is the dependency between days that matters a lot here.

Comment: Good point.  Assume no dependency!

Comment: But then it is trivial!

Comment: The way you calculated the standard deviation already assumes that the daily sales are independent! As Micheal M pointed out, if daily sales are independent, the vendor should just forget everything which happened before and assume that next day sales are normal with mean 150 and sd 50.

Comment: The statistics you offer (where the weekly variance is five times the daily variance) suggest you are considering the daily sales to be independent.  If that's the case, it means the M-Th sales tell you *absolutely nothing* about the following F sales and the answer would be the chance that a Normal variate exceeds its mean: namely, 50%. But your question indicates you don't believe all these assumptions.  The practical issue, then, is to estimate a valid model.  *What do your data tell you?*

Comment: This depends very much on the independence of days. On the one hand, we might consider a fixed pool of customers coming to get their once-a-week hot dog, in which case many people coming early in the week indicates that fewer will come later. On the other hand, we might assume a large population where each hot dog purchase is totally independent, in which case sales on one day have no effect on sales on another day.